# rows added via javascript to table inside form don't submit

Tags: javascript, php

Hy, I have read many discussion on this argument but I just can't find a solution.
I have  table inside a form, the first rows of this table are displayed by a php script, I won't the user to be able to add a row to the table so that he can insert a new set of values. the problem is that this new rows that I insert don't get submitted. here is the php code

```
    <form method="post">
<table name="elencoAltriContatti" id="elencoAltriContatti">
<button type="button" class="btn primary success" onClick="showNewContatti();" name="nuovo">NUOVO</button>
<tr>
<td><p><strong>Nome</strong></p></td>
<td><p><strong>Qualifica</strong></p></td>
<td><p><strong>Email</strong></p></td>
<td><p><strong>Telefono</strong></p></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php 
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><p><input type=\"text\" id=\"nome\" name=\"NOME[]\" value=\"".$row['NOME']."\" class=\"input-text3\" onchange=\"selectCheckbox('".$i."')\"></p></td>";
  echo "<td><p><input type=\"text\" id=\"qualifica\" name=\"QUALIFICA[]\" value=\"".$row['QUALIFICA']."\" class=\"input-text3\" onchange=\"selectCheckbox('".$i."')\"></p></td>";
  echo "<td><p><input type=\"text\" id=\"email\" name=\"EMAIL[]\" value=\"".$row['EMAIL']."\" class=\"input-text3\" onchange=\"selectCheckbox('".$i."')\"> </p></td>";
  echo "<td><p><input type=\"text\" id=\"telefono\" name=\"TELEFONO[]\" value=\"".$row['TELEFONO']."\" class=\"input-text3\" onchange=\"selectCheckbox('".$i."')\"></p></td>";
  echo "<td><input id=\"".$i."\" name=\"CHECKBOX[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" style=\"float:right\"></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
?>

</table>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
     <button type="reset" name="reset"  class="btn info">CANCELLA</button>
     <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn info" >SALVA</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

wich works just fine, and here is the javascript function I use

```
function showNewContatti(){
  var table = document.getElementById('elencoAltriContatti');
  var lastRow = table.rows.length;
  var row=table.insertRow(lastRow);
  var nome=row.insertCell(0);
  var qualifica=row.insertCell(1);
  var email=row.insertCell(2);
  var telefono=row.insertCell(3);
  var checkbox=row.insertCell(4);
  nome.innerHTML="<p><input type=\"text\" id=\"nome\" name=\"NOME[]\" class=\"input-text3\" onchange=\"selectCheckbox('"+lastRow+"')\"></p>";
  qualifica.innerHTML="<p><input type=\"text\" id=\"qualifica\" name=\"QUALIFICA[]\" class=\"input-text3\" onchange=\"selectCheckbox("+lastRow+")\"></p>";
  email.innerHTML="<p><input type=\"text\" id=\"email\" name=\"EMAIL[]\" class=\"input-text3\" onchange=\"selectCheckbox("+lastRow+")\"></p>";
  telefono.innerHTML="<p><input type=\"text\" id=\"telefono\" name=\"TELEFONO[]\" class=\"input-text3\" onchange=\"selectCheckbox("+lastRow+")\"></p>";
  checkbox.innerHTML="<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\""+lastRow+"\" name=\"CHECKBOX[]\" style=\"float:right\">";}
```

new rows added with this function just don't get submitted, do you have some ideas? 
thank's for the help

EDIT: I have changed my javascript function, now it looks like this:

```
 var table = document.getElementById('elencoAltriContatti');
  var lastRow = table.rows.length;
  var Iterator=lastRow; 
  var row=table.insertRow(lastRow);

  var nome = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell = document.createElement('input');
  cell.type = 'text';
  cell.name = 'nome' + Iterator;
  cell.id = 'nome' + Iterator;
  cell.className= 'input-text3';
  cell.onchange= function(){
    selectCheckbox(Iterator);
 };
  nome.appendChild(cell);
```

but I still have the same problem, what else can I do?

Comment: The innerHTML is not 'registering' the new elements within the DOM. You will need to use the full method of createElement('input') etc

Answer (score 0):

In your innerHTML lines, you are passing the  same name attributes as in the original. Form elements are POSTed as name=value pairs. Two form elements must not have the same name.

To add form elements in javascript, you should build the name attribute dynamicaly:

```
i=1;
name='nome'+i;
html="<input type='text' name='" + name + "' />";
i++; //etc...
```

Comment: but in this way I get many elements with different ID's, I want to create arrays, multiple elements with the same name but with an [], such as nome[], shouldn't create an array containing all the values?

Comment: No, the point is you cannot submit multiple form elements with the same name attribute. Notice how in my code the name attribute comes from a variable. In yours it's part of the string.

Comment: for how to use arrays, please see: (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)